# Front dial damage

Tags: effective-aperture

I have nikon d300 and the front dial is damage. How can assign other button to change the aperture? And also it has snapbridge or bluetooth? I don't have computer or laptop to transfer photos.

Comment: To transfer photos where? To your phone?

Comment: You have 2 entirely different questions, which should be posted separately

Comment: Yes sir. To android phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about the front dial other than repairing it. Such cameras are designed to be operated that way and there are no redundant controls. Even though you can swap the dials, some features require both or constantly swapping would be impractical.

The D300 is rather old and has no Bluetooth which implies no SnapBridge support since that is just an app that uses Bluetooth.

The best way to transfer photos is to use a card reader. Those are available for under $10. They are faster than using the camera and do not use up its battery either.

Comment: Hi sir. I just change the aperture from f22-f1.8 but I forgot how I do it. I remember I just used the rear dial. Weird. I will look for card reader from camera to my android phone. Thank you very much. Appreciated.

Comment: How about i will invest for vertical battery grip? It's sound better. It has also front and rear dial. Plus more fps and battery power. Wohh!

Answer (score 0):

You can [swap the two dials](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LjK4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT279&lpg=PT279&dq=d300%20swap%20dials&source=bl&ots=4MSlz1wuRN&sig=CLs2H4-TuBewRRTRxiTnCQ_N8Rk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi84ubRmfvXAhVB6SYKHRDTA5UQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=d300%20swap%20dials&f=false) so the rear controls the aperture. It is a custom setting. Not very convenient if you have to switch it back and forth but it might help you in the short term.